# Problem II.3.13: How to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{m}|(x | u_{k})|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}$ for an orthonormal system of an inner product space

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products, orthonormal, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm doing **Problem II.3.13.a** in textbook *Analysis I* by Amann/Escher.

> [image]

in which

> $B=\left\{u_{0}, \ldots, u_{m}\right\}$ is an orthonormal system in an inner product space $(E,(\cdot | \cdot ))$ and $F :=\operatorname{span}(B)$.

I tried to use the CS inequality as hinted, but I get a weaker inequality:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{m} |(x | u_{k})|^{2} \le \sum_{k=0}^{m} \|x\|^2 \|u_k\|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \|x\|^2 = (m+1)\|x\|^2$$

Please help me solve **(a)**. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some manipulation, we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^m|(x\mid u_k)|^2&=(x\mid\sum_{k=0}^m(x\mid u_k)u_k)\\
&\leq\|x\|\cdot\left\|\sum_{k=0}^m(x\mid u_k)u_k\right\|\\
&=\|x\|\left(\sum_{k=0}^m|(x\mid u_k)|^2\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
Rearranging, we obtain the result.

Comment: It's sad that I still not get the desired inequality by following your hint. Please have a check on my attempt! $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=0}^m|(x|u_k)|^2 &=\left (x \;\middle|\; \sum_{k=0}^m (x | u_k)u_k \right) &&\le \|x \| \left \|\sum_{k=0}^m (x|u_k)u_k \right \| \\
& \le \| x \| \left (\sum_{k=0}^m \| (x | u_k)u_k \| \right) &&= \| x \|  \left (\sum_{k=0}^m |(x | u_k)| \|u_k \| \right) \\
&=\| x \|  \left (\sum_{k=0}^m |(x | u_k)| \right) && \le \| x \|  \left (\sum_{k=0}^m \| x \| \| u_k \| \right) \\
&= \| x \|  \left (\sum_{k=0}^m \| x \| \right) && = (m+1) \| x \|^2 \end{aligned}$$

Comment: @LeAnhDung Instead of using the triangle inequality immediately after your first application of Cauchy-Schwarz, you should use the fact that $B$ is orthonormal to show
$$\left\|\sum_{k=0}^m \left(x\mid u_k\right)u_k\right\| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^m \left|\left(x\mid u_k\right)\right|^2}$$
(which is basically the Pythagorean theorem)

Comment: Hi @BrianMoehring, I tried your hint but to no avail. Could you please have a check on this? $$\begin{aligned}\|x \| \left \|\sum_{k=0}^m (x|u_k)u_k \right \| &=  \|x \| \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^m \left|\left(x\mid u_k\right)\right|^2} &&\le \|x \| \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^m  \|x \|^2 \|u_k\|^2 } \\ &= \|x \| \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^m  \|x \|^2 }  &&= \sqrt{m+1}\|x \|^2  \end{aligned}$$

Comment: @LeAnhDung You need to stop and see what you've proven.  After you show/use the equality in my hint, you will have shown $$\sum_{k=0}^m \left|\left( x \mid u_k\right)\right|^2 \leq \|x\| \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^m \left|\left(x\mid u_k\right)\right|^2}$$

Don't use any more approximations.  Solve this inequality.

Comment: @LeAnhDung I have updated my answer.  If you have any questions about the steps, let me know.

Comment: Oh I got it ;) Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Aweygan, I asked a strongly related question about orthonormal system [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321178/problem-ii-3-12-prove-that-x-p-fx-inf-y-in-f-x-y-for-an-ort). It's unfortunate that I've not received any response since then. Could you please have a look at it? Honestly, my question is very short and it will not take you much time ;)